# Как сделать окно сразу активным при его создании? tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

Я делаю калькулятор который при нажатии кнопки f9 запускается. Задача: нужно чтоб окно было поверх всех окон(это я смог сделать)и при запуске калькулятора поле ввода сразу ставало активным и туда можно было писать текст. Проблема: хоть окно и создается поверх всего, но оно становиться активным только после нажатия, то есть текст удается писать только после нажатия на окно. Может кто знает что нужно дописать чтоб туда можно было сразу писать текст.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter


window = tkinter.Tk()
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.place(x=10, y=10)
# уберите комментарий чтобы установить фокус при старте приложения
# entry.focus_set()
window.mainloop()
```